# Shaded background box turns always black, in LyX

Tags: lyx

I'm trying to insert a shaded-background box, but in the result PDF it always turns to be black shaded-box, regradless of the actual colour I chose in the settings; Nevertheless, the text after the shaded-box appears in the color I chose for the box, as you can see below; How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

The minimal example file of the above image:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\boxbgcolor #bab9b9
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\leftmargin 2.54cm
\topmargin 3.18cm
\rightmargin 2.54cm
\bottommargin 3.18cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Box Shaded
position "t"
hor_pos "c"
has_inner_box 1
inner_pos "t"
use_parbox 0
use_makebox 0
width "100col%"
special "none"
height "1in"
height_special "totalheight"
thickness "0.4pt"
separation "3pt"
shadowsize "4pt"
framecolor "black"
backgroundcolor "none"
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang english
dfasfsdafasdf
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
sfasfdafsafsaf
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
fsdafsdafa
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
dsfsdaf
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
sd
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
fad
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\lang english
saf
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: What steps in LyX do I take to set the color? (give steps to me like I'm 5 years old. I can't find that dialog you have with "Background Colors". Also, what is your LyX version?

Comment: @scottkosty Document > Setting > Colors. 
I'm using LyX 2.3.1-1

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it works for me. Can you post a minimal example file? For more information, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty Can I upload a file to here?

Comment: Please read the page :). It has a section called "How do I post a .lyx file on a forum or a Q&A post without attachments (e.g., tex.stackexchange.com)?"

Comment: @scottkosty Oh, I saw it now, thank you! I added the example file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the example file. I can confirm the output you see using an old LyX version. This is a [bug](https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/8642) that was fixed starting with LyX 2.3.4. Thus, if you upgrade to the newest LyX version you will get correct output.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! How can I upgrade my version? Can I do that and keep all the settings, or will it require downloading LyX from scratch and "ruin" everything?

Comment: @AlorK. What operating system do you use? If by chance you use Ubuntu there is a simple way to automatically update. If you use a different OS, things should work fine and you can download the new version from the lyx.org website. You can look at Help > About to find your user directory (which contains your preferences). Before you update, back up that user directory. If anything goes wrong, you have that backup.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've installed the new version now, and it works indeed!